# Reload view using data from map

Tags: uitableview, android-mapview, reload, nsurlrequest, segue

I'm new to Objective C / iOS but hopefully I can explain clearly enough to get some assistance:

The application has a map with pins and callouts. Tapping a callout loads a table view based on data in the annotation (view):

`- (void)mapView:(CPMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {`

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowUserClusterTable" sender:view];
```

}

The user can perform an action from that table view which should then modify the table view.

1. Click row in table view, perform action in a modal view, data sent to web server
2. Modal view dismissed. Notification sent to map controller to refresh data from web server (annotations are refreshed)
3. User returned to table view
4. Table view is not showing updated data

Data is received via an API call, therefore in the completion function I'm posting a notification to the table view to refresh data. The notification is received, and if I knew how to access the new data here it would all be fine!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reloading the data from the tableView??

```
[[self tableView] reloadData];
```